# Environment variable in /etc/environment with pound (hash) sign in the value

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

On Ubuntu 12.04, I have an environment variable defined in `/etc/environment` like this:

```
FOO="value_before#value_after"
```

When I ssh into the server to check the value, I get this:

```
$ env | grep FOO
FOO=value_before
```

I'm guessing it is treating the `#` as a comment and stripping it out, however, this works:

```
$ . /etc/environment
$ export FOO
$ env | grep FOO
FOO=value_before#value_after
```

I've tried escaping the `#` like this:

```
FOO="value_before\#value_after"
```

But that doesn't work, instead I just get this:

```
FOO=value_before\
```

Any ideas on how to make the hash be treated like part of the value? Any help would be great.

Values I've tried in the `/etc/environment` file:

```
FOO='value_before#value_after'
FOO="value_before#value_after"
FOO='"value_before#value_after"'
FOO="value_before\#value_after"
FOO='value_before\#value_after'
```

And other various combinations of the above. A lot of these will work when you just normally set them in the shell. But they don't seem to work in the `/etc/environment` file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is read by the pam_env module. Given that the pam_env module expects them to be "simple" KEY=VALUE pairs (doesn't need quotes) and also supports comments identified by #, it assumes that a # and anything following it in a VALUE are a comment. Also, note that it does not support any concept of escaping.

This can be seen in the following snippet from the _parse_env_file function in [pam_env.c](https://fossies.org/dox/Linux-PAM-1.2.1/modules_2pam__env_2pam__env_8c_source.html).

```
/* now find the end of value */
mark = key;
while(mark[0] != '\n' && mark[0] != '#' && mark[0] != '\0')
    mark++;
if (mark[0] != '\0')
    mark[0] = '\0';
```

The above snippet walks each character of the VALUE portion until it finds a `\n`, `#` or `\0`. It then overwrites that character with a `\0`.

This effectively strips off the `#` and everything following. **Note:** This is a feature **not** a bug. It is the comment feature.

So, at this point you cannot have values in `/etc/environment` that include a `#` or a `\n` or `\0` in the middle of the value. It also looks like from the code that the keys need to be alpha-numeric.

Comment: Whoa, nailed it! Thanks for the detailed explanation, I've marked this as the accepted solution.

Comment: This is the stupidest, nastiest thing I have ever seen in a very, very long time. 8 hours wasted because of lazy programming in PAM. At the very least, there should be a simple comment line WARNING ABOUT THIS BEHAVIOR.

Comment: AKWF:  There's a single mention in `pam_env.conf(5)` and `environment.d(5)` manual pages about "# at the start of a line" but the actual behavior clearly scans for "#" at any place in the line.  I'd call this a bug, but good luck trying to get PAM documentation updated.

Answer (score 3):

I was never able to find a way around this limitation in `/etc/environment`, the documentation seems to state that `/etc/environment` is a [simple](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pam_env.8.html) environment file:

```
This module can also parse a file with simple KEY=VAL pairs on separate 
lines (/etc/environment by default).
```

Which might mean it won't let you escape values using quotes or the `\` character, despite other places in the [documentation maybe saying this is possible](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/pam_env.conf.5.html):

```
(Possibly non-existent) environment variables may be used in values using 
the ${string} syntax and (possibly non-existent) PAM_ITEMs may be used in 
values using the @{string} syntax. Both the $ and @ characters can be 
backslash escaped to be used as literal values values can be delimited with ""
```

[Or maybe not](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/pam.d.5.html):

```
The file is made up of a list of rules, each rule is typically placed on a
single line, [...] Comments are preceded with `#´ marks and extend to the 
next end of line.
```

Anyway, to get around this limitation, I moved my global environment variables into a file in `/etc/profile.d` as [discussed in this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/261823/server-specific-environment-variables-etc-profile-or-etc-profile-d?rq=1). I still consider this question unanswered, but I wanted to make sure there was a linked workaround for posterity.

Comment: `pam_env.conf` and `pam.conf` are different files from `/etc/environment`, that's why the documentation says different things for them.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in /etc/environment to escape the #(as it treated as a comment) as it is being parsed by he PAM module "pam_env" and it treats it as a simple list of KEY=VAL pairs and sets up the environment accordingly. It is not bash/shell, the parser has no language for doing variable expansion or characters escaping.

Answer (score -1):

Single quotes.

```
$ FOO='foo#bar'
$ echo $FOO
foo#bar
```

Comment: That was one of the first values I tried, while it works in the shell, sadly, it doesn't work in `/etc/environment`, I've updated my question with some examples of values I've tried.